# Exposing Python function with variadic arguments from c++

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I would like to expose to python a function accepting required positional arguments,optional keyword arguments, variadic positional arguments, and variadic keyword arguments.

For example:

```
def f( a,b,c=0,*args,**kwargs )
```

Is it possible to expose a function with the same prototype from c++ using `boost::python`?

using `boost::python::raw_function` I am only able  to define a function that accepts a `boost::python::list` and a `boost::python::dictionary`, so it is impossible to define some positional argument.

For Example:

```
namespace py = boost::python;

py::object test_kwargs(py::tuple args, py::dict kwargs)
{
    std::cout << "args size : " << py::len(args) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "kwargs size : " << py::len(kwargs) << std::endl;
    return py::object();
}



BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(MyModule)
{
    py::def("test_kwargs", py::raw_function(&test_kwargs));
}
```

But if I would like to define:

```
py::object test_kwargs_bis(int i, py::tuple args, py::dict kwargs)
{
    return py::object();
}
```

How can expose it to python?

Comment: I 'm not familiar with Boost, but `test_kwargs` looks more like it is equivalent to `def test_kwargs(args: tuple, kwargs: dict)`, not `def test_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: @chepner, you can read the docs here 
 https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/function_invocation_and_creation/boost_python_raw_function_hpp.html